# Modify default memoir chapter style

Tags: sectioning, formatting, memoir, chapters

I'm using `memoir` and using its default chapter style.
what I'm looking to do is to change the format from

> chapter 1
>
> chapter title

to something like this:

> chapter 1: chapter title

I'm new to LaTeX and I've been struggling with this all day reading manual and searching the net

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I would like the title to be centered as well

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to include 'thanks', simpliy upvote any good answers you may receive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}    % To harmonise the font sizes
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\chaptitlefont}   % idem
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{:\quad}        % To set the line
```

(for example).

The macro `\afterchapternum` is called by `memoir` after setting 'Chapter n' and before setting 'This is my Chapter'.

The default value is this:

```
\def\afterchapternum{\par\nobreak\vskip \midchapskip}
```

The `memoir` manual describes this in §6.5, around pp 80-82.

---

**Note:** Added font harmonisation. My thanks to @lockstep.

Comment: Many Thanks Brent... it works, but I had to remove the titlesec package that i was using for centering the all chapter titles... is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @M.Habib There almost certainly is, but I'm afraid I can't research exactly how to do it right now, sorry. However, you might like to take a look at the various pre-defined chapter styles available in `memoir` -- try `\chapterstyle{crosshead}`, for example, in place of my answer.

Comment: Use `\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\chaptitlefont\centering}`.

Comment: Many thanks Brent and lockstep ... works perfectly now

Answer (score 5):

A possible solution:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fonttitle}{\chaptitlefont}
\makechapterstyle{mystyle}{%
\def\chapterheadstart{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
\def\printchaptername{}
\def\printchapternum{}
\def\printchapternonum{}
\def\printchaptertitle##1{\fonttitle \@chapapp\space \fonttitle \thechapter:\space \fonttitle ##1}
\def\afterchaptertitle{\par\nobreak\vskip \afterchapskip}
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\lipsum

\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The result (page 1 for example):

[image]