# Changing font size of chapter headings the same as that of section

Tags: sectioning, memoir, fontsize

[image]

I have a memoir document that has `mystyle` chapter copied from [Modify default memoir chapter style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97465/modify-default-memoir-chapter-style).

How can I change the font size of the chapter to the same as that of section? Or, how I can I change the fontsize of chapters in general?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\title{Document}
\author{prosseek}
% }

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97465/modify-default-memoir-chapter-style
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fonttitle}{\chaptitlefont}
\makechapterstyle{mystyle}{%
\def\chapterheadstart{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
\def\printchaptername{}
\def\printchapternum{}
\def\printchapternonum{}
\def\printchaptertitle##1{\fonttitle \space \fonttitle \thechapter.\space \fonttitle ##1}
\def\afterchaptertitle{\par\nobreak\vskip \afterchapskip}
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{The Domain Problem and Stakeholders}
\section{First}
abcdef. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've defined `\fonttitle` to be the font for your chapters, simply replace

```
\newcommand{\fonttitle}{\chaptitlefont}
```

with

```
\newcommand{\fonttitle}{\secheadstyle}
```

Note that `\chaptitlefont` corresponds to `\Huge\bfseries` while `\secheadstyle` (the default used in sections) corresponds to `\Large\bfseries` (see Section 6.9 of `memoir` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)).

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}

\title{Document}
\author{prosseek}
% }

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97465/modify-default-memoir-chapter-style
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fonttitle}{\secheadstyle}
\makechapterstyle{mystyle}{%
\def\chapterheadstart{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
\def\printchaptername{}
\def\printchapternum{}
\def\printchapternonum{}
\def\printchaptertitle##1{\fonttitle \space \fonttitle \thechapter.\space \fonttitle ##1}
\def\afterchaptertitle{\par\nobreak\vskip \afterchapskip}
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{The Domain Problem and Stakeholders}
\section{First}
abcdef.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

BTW: all the redundant `\fonttitle` can be eliminated, you can simply write:

```
\def\printchaptertitle##1{\fonttitle \space \thechapter.\space ##1}
```

Moreover, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are not needed since the code between them doesn't contain the the character `@`.