# How to modify chapter name in headers in memoir

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, memoir, chapters

I modified the chapter title to be shown as `1. ...`, but the headings still show `CHAPTER`.
How can I remove the `chapter` in headings? Is there a way to modify the chapter style in the contents and heading at the same time?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Document}
\author{prosseek}
% }

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97465/modify-default-memoir-chapter-style
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fonttitle}{\chaptitlefont}
\makechapterstyle{mystyle}{%
\def\chapterheadstart{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
\def\printchaptername{}
\def\printchapternum{}
\def\printchapternonum{}
\def\printchaptertitle##1{\fonttitle \space \fonttitle \thechapter.\space \fonttitle ##1}
\def\afterchaptertitle{\par\nobreak\vskip \afterchapskip}
}
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{The Domain Problem and Stakeholders}
\section{First}
\lipsum 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chapter styles and page styles are two separate things. You only changed the chapter style.

If the `headings` style is ok for you and you only want to remove `CHAPTER` then use

```
\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
}
\pagestyle{headings}
```

You might want to consider adding `\nouppercaseheads` before `\pagestyle{...}`, this removes the uppercaseness of the headers.